# Progressive Web App - Service Worker not serving start_URL

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, web, progressive-web-apps

Was playing around with the progressive web app. I've trying to make web app install banner working but I keep receiving `service worker does not successfully serve the manifest's start_url` after I debugging using Lighthouse (Picture below). Currently I'm hosting my website using azure.

**NEW:**
I checked all my cache, start_url, and also my service worker to see everything match. But it still gives me the same error.

[image]

I'm not sure if it's my `start_url` or my `service-worker`problem. Below is my code.

`manifest.json`

```
  {
   "short_name": "MY EXPERTS",
   "name": "MYEXPERT",
   "icons": [
    {
      "src": "Images/petronas_logo_192.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "192x192"
    },
    {
      "src": "Images/petronas_logo_192.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "512x512"
    }
 ],

 "background_color": "#FFFFFF",
 "theme_color": "#67BCFF",
 "display": "standalone",
 "start_url": "/Home/Index"
}
```

`AddServiceWorker.js`

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
navigator.serviceWorker.register('/service-worker.js').
    then(function (registration) {
        // Registration was successful``
        console.log('ServiceWorker registration successful with scope: ', 
registration.scope);
    }).catch(function (err) {
        // registration failed :(
        console.log('ServiceWorker registration failed: ', err);
    });
}
```

`service-worker.js`

```
 self.addEventListener('install', e => {
 e.waitUntil(
    caches.open('airhorner').then(cache => {
        return cache.addAll([
            '/',
            '/?utm_source=homescreen',
            '/Home/About',
            '/Home/Index',
            '/Home/Contact'
        ])
            .then(() => self.skipWaiting());
    })
  )
});

self.addEventListener('activate', event => {
 event.waitUntil(self.clients.claim());
});

self.addEventListener('fetch', event => {
  event.respondWith(
    caches.match(event.request).then(response => {
        return response || fetch(event.request);
    })
  );
});
```

My Browser Cache :

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Noted from [Register A service worker](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers/#register_a_service_worker),

> If we register the service worker file at `/example/sw.js`, then the service worker would only see `fetch` events for pages whose URL starts with `/example/` (i.e. `/example/page1/`, `/example/page2/`).

Inline with the shown error and given in this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/lighthouse/audits/cache-contains-start_url), check the following:

> 1. Define a `start_url` property in your `manifest.json` file.
> 2. Ensure that your service worker properly caches a resource that matches the value of `start_url`.

Also, check this [tutorial](https://abendigo.github.io/2016/07/17/pwa_step_one.html) and see if it will help you.

Comment: I went through all of your links. Checked my cache, doing a bit of trial and error but I still received the same error. I updated my question with a screenshot of my cache.

Comment: i had my service worker inside a subdirectory. that was causing the issue. thanks

Comment: Running the audit in incognito mode resolves this issue for me. 
No idea why though

Comment: furthermore the error disappears when I add a route to the cache that does not exist. Its magic, but also very poor.

Comment: OMG. I've spent like two days fighting with this and the issue was... THAT!?!?!?!?!  GAH!

Answer (score 3):

Just a note... you notice above that the pages are being served over "https."  But, if you have everything else right, and are not using https, you will get this same error message.

Answer (score 3):

there guys, been struggling with same issue just to find that my html link tag was missing, make sure you are indicating where is your manifest file located on your website header:

```
<link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json">
```

Answer (score 3):

## **Answered**

- Go to your **public** folder,
- Go to your **manifest.json** file,
- Now add `"start_url": "/",` to the json object.
- See example below.

`{ "name": "Occasionally Frustrated", "short_name": "Occasionally Frustrated", "start_url": "/", "display": "standalone" }`

Answer (score 0):

You should provide the url in `"start_url"`, if you are using the localhost it should containg the next: `"start_url": "http://localhost:8080/index.html"`,

Comment: never provide host on start_url

Answer (score 0):

Exclude /wp-content/plugins/super-progressive-web-apps/public/js/register-sw.js
from cache plugin. It works for me.

Comment: Please expand your answer with an explanation