# how to solve Cant detect servicewoker.js in cpanel

Tags: php, laravel, cpanel, progressive-web-apps

I'm using https://github.com/silviolleite/laravel-pwa this package for PWA.

After using this it will perfectly work fine on the localhost. But after uploading in Cpanel it does not detect the service worker. Here is my screenshot of my localhost and Cpanel **lighthouse** report
This is my localhost screenshot
[image]

and this is my cpanel lighthouse report
[image]

help me to figure out why this is happening

Comment: Sounds like something is different between the environments. Are PHP versions the same? Is https enabled correctly on cPanel?

Comment: https not enabled but service why it is not registering the service worker...Is it relate to the https???

Comment: I haven't worked with PWA, but it sounds like that might cause that error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46726966/progressive-web-app-service-worker-not-serving-start-url

Comment: and this is for just my tesing

Comment: the problem is for https thanks  @spudly